# Flask-SQLAlchemy insert records with multiple foreign keys

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, foreign-keys, flask-sqlalchemy

I have 3 tables:

```
class User(db.Model):
   id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
   name = db.Column(db.String)
   successes = db.relationship('Success', backref='user', lazy='dynamic')

class Success(db.Model):
   id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
   package = db.Column(db.String)
   user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'))
   trial_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('trials.id'))

class Trials(db.Model):
   id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
   description = db.Column(db.String)
   successes = db.relationship('Success', backref='attempt', lazy='dynamic')
```

I can insert the data in Success and user table using :

```
user.successes.extend(success_objects_list)
db.session.add(user)
db.session.add_all(success_objects_list)
db.session.commit()
```

This takes care of the foreign-key **user_id**.

How do I simultaneously insert data data in **Trial** Table and take care of the second foreign-Key **trial_id** ??

Comment: Why can't you do the exact same thing?

Comment: @univerio wouldn't that insert records 2 times ? As once i have already done by extending the user.successes.

Comment: Have you tried it? By extending `user.successes` you add the `Success` instances to the session and associate them with the `User` instance. By extending `trial.successes`, you add the `Success` instances to the session and associate them with the `Trials` instance, but because they are already in the session, they don't get added twice.

Comment: @univerio yes I tried it, and it worked. thanks :)  You should post this as an answer and I'll mark it as solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the exact same thing with `trial.successes` and it should just work. By extending `user.successes` you add the `Success` instances to the session and associate them with the `User` instance. By extending `trial.successes`, you add the `Success` instances to the session and associate them with the `Trials` instance, but because they are already in the session, they don't get added twice.